# In Cake PHP 2.x - How can I include components that are stored in a subfolder of the Components folder?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

For example, from within a Controller (this doesn't work):

```
$this->Components->load('api/UserComponent');
```

... calling a component from folder structure like so:

```
app/Controller/Component/api/UserComponent.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this into your bootstrap: it will tell cake to consider also your subdirectory when loading components from your controller

```
App::build(array(
    'Controller/Component' => array(
        APP.'Controller/Component/api/'
    )
));
```

after that you should be able to include and use component as if it would be in `Component` directory

Comment: Hi, alternative for CakePHP easy is https://packagist.org/packages/eom/plugin-cakephp-loadsubcomponents

Answer (score 2):

**Solutions is two in CakePHP 2.x**

**Add now Path by App::build()**

```
// Append Path in bootstrap.php
App::build(array(
    'Controller/Component' => array(
        APP . 'Controller'.DS.'Component'.DS.'Reports' . DS,
    )
), App::APPEND);

// Load in controller MyController ....
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session', 'ReportUsers');
// In controller
$this->ReportUsers->Demo('bla..bla..');

// OR load in fly in action form controller.
$this->ReportUsers = $this->Components->load('ReportUsers');
$this->ReportUsers->Demo('bla..bla..');
```

**Or by CakePlugin, Create one Plugin Reports for example:**

```
// Add Plugin in file bootstrap.php
CakePlugin::load('Reports');

// MyController use Example
// Load in controller MyController ....
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session', 'Reports.ReportUsers');
// In controller
$this->ReportUsers->Demo('bla..bla..');

// OR load in fly in action form controller.
$this->ReportUsers = $this->Components->load('Reports.ReportUsers');
$this->ReportUsers->Demo('bla..bla..');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your components in a sub folder under `Component` folder. If you want to better organize your classes use plugins.

Comment: not to argue with you, but `$this->loadComponent('MyGroup/MyComponent')` followed by `$this->{'MyGroup/MyComponent'}->myMethod();` work fine on CakePHP3. The actual component code is indeed in the `MyGroup` subfolder. Is this an 'undocumented', discouraged feature that may break soon, or simply a lot of things have changed since mid-2015 when you wrote your answer?